# Using count points in polygon tool in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, count

I have two layers: one point and one polygon grid layer. Trying to count the number of points in each grid polygon and have it become an attribute in the polygon layer. Currently using ArcMap 10 with HawthsTools>Analysis tools>Count points in polygon to accomplish this task manually, but I want to bake it into a model. I can't figure out how to add HawthsTools into ModelBuilder.

Why is this?

I have not yet installed Geospatial Modeling Environment, which is the new iteration of HawthsTools.

Does GME play nice with ModelBuilder?

If not, what solutions can you suggest?

The closest I've gotten is finding a python script that will count points in polygons.
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/23838-Using-Point-in-Polygon-in-Modelbuilder.

Can I use this in a model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First use [Intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000.htm) to add the polygon ID to each point.

Then use [Summary Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000.htm) on those points to obtain a count of how many times each polygon ID occurs in the stats table.

Then use [Join Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000065000000) to join the count field from the stats table onto the polygons by using the polygon ID as the key field.

All of the above can be used in ModelBuilder.